# Flink keyed state clean up for incremental rocksdb checkpointing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink job that would persist large keyed state in rocksdb backend. We are using incremental checkpointing strategy.  As time goes by, the size of the state become a problem. We have checked the state ttl solution but it does not support incremental rocksdb states.

What would be the best approach for this problem if I really need incremental checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that is often used is to manipulate the state in some kind of ProcessFunction, and use a timer to clear the state when it is no longer needed -- e.g., if it hasn't been accessed for several hours. ProcessFunctions are able to have both event-time and processing-time timers, so you can choose whichever is more appropriate for your use case.

See the [expiring state exercise](https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-processfunction.html) on the Flink training site for an example of using timers to clear state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually we have already checked this approach. The only concern for us is that there is a statement 'Timers are always asynchronously checkpointed, except for the combination of RocksDB backend / with incremental snapshots / with heap-based timers (will be resolved with FLINK-10026). ' What does this really mean? Is it mean that the timers won't be stored in the state backend? What would happen to the timers when failure happened if I use incremental snapshot?

Comment: Timers have been and continue to be checkpointed. Before Flink 1.6, timers were always synchronously checkpointed. Now they are normally asynchronously checkpointed -- making it more practical to have lots of timers -- but in some cases are still synchronously checkpointed. This will be resolved with FLINK-10026. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9485 for a more complete picture.